# Book where a girl who makes potions is framed for trying to hurt a princess

Tags: story-identification, books

The book is about a girl that makes potions and uses throwing needles. she is framed for trying to hurt her best friend, the princess, tries to clear her name. It's based in the past era and the people (guards/bounty hunters) looking for her put a type of tracking potion on her, its supposed to be impossible to get off. They follow a rumor that someone got the tracking potion off them in the past with the help of a gypsy. So she goes into the swamps to get help from a gypsy. At the end she falls in love with a guy that she randomly meets on and off along the way but its later found out that he's a prince and the princess was supposed to marry the guy. The princess and the guy don't get married and it ends with the Potion girl kissing the Prince or something. I think the guy had a pet and that the prince's name started with an F. I read this anywhere from 2012-2016. It was a glossy hardcover, that was green with something red on it I think?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You could maybe make this question stronger by looking at the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking a good question.  Details you could add include when you read it, and what the cover looked like.

Answer (score 5):

[Poison](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8113512.Poison) by Bridget Zinn

> Sixteen-year-old Kyra, a highly-skilled potions master, is the only
>   one who knows her kingdom is on the verge of destruction—which means
>   she’s the only one who can save it. Faced with no other choice, Kyra
>   decides to do what she does best: poison the kingdom’s future ruler,
>   who also happens to be her former best friend.
>
> But, for the first time ever, her poisoned dart . . . misses.
>
> Now a fugitive instead of a hero, Kyra is caught in a game of
>   hide-and-seek with the king’s army and her potioner ex-boyfriend, Hal.
>   At least she’s not alone. She’s armed with her vital potions, a
>   too-cute pig, and Fred, the charming adventurer she can’t stop
>   thinking about. Kyra is determined to get herself a second chance (at
>   murder), but will she be able to find and defeat the princess before
>   Hal and the army find her?
>
> Kyra is not your typical murderer, and she’s certainly no
>   damsel-in-distress—she’s the lovable and quick-witted hero of this
>   romantic novel that has all the right ingredients to make teen girls
>   swoon.